# How can I make text in a div tag responsive?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I've got basic web design skills atm, I'm working on my portfolio and need help with the landing page please.

I want the heading and sub heading on my page to resize when the browser resizes, but it's not working.

The body font is 12px but I only want the font to resize in the div tags not the body text.

I have 2 div tags with ID tags for the CSS like so.

```
<div id="heading">
    this is my heading text
</div>

<div id="subheading">
    this is my subheading text
</div>
```

This is the css.

```
#heading {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    font-size: 55px;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
}

#subheading {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    font-size: 36px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I want both headings to reduce in size by about 20/30% when the window/browser is resized 
but when I change the values for the tablet css, different to these values in the desktop view
everything changes straight away. I want the text to stay the same in desktop view and only change size in tablet view. Hope this makes sense.

Appreciate a reply.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)**

**For Instance,**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    #heading {
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            padding-top:3%;
            padding-bottom:1%;
            font-size:55px;
            color:#FFF;
            position:relative;
            font-size: xxpt; /*put your size here*/
}

 #subheading {

            float:left;
            width:100%;
            padding-top:3%;
            padding-bottom:3%;
            font-size:36px;
            position:relative;
            font-size: xxpt; /*put your size here*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) /* for ipad */ {
            #heading {
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            padding-top:3%;
            padding-bottom:1%;
            font-size:55px;
            color:#FFF;
            position:relative;
            font-size: xxpt; /*put your size here*/
}

 #subheading {

            float:left;
            width:100%;
            padding-top:3%;
            padding-bottom:3%;
            font-size:36px;
            position:relative;
            font-size: xxpt; /*put your size here*/
}
```

***PS:** The pixel values are used as an approximation for illustrative purposes. You can replace them with your desired values.*

Comment: Thank you, I got it working after trial and error over and over again, but now the text is moving all over the place. I was it central in the same position. It's fine in desktop view but in tablet or small it shifts to the right..

Comment: Ok this is a mess and the images are missing but the main issue I am having is that there is a margin to each side, I really don't want this and set margin and padding to 0 before coding the site, but ever since changing the media queries it's appeared. http://jsfiddle.net/fSYSJ/11/ I really appreciate your time so far

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the width to  100% ever ! Even better - remove the width and it will work ;d

```
#heading {
padding-top:3%;
padding-bottom:1%;
font-size:55px;
color:#FFF;
position:relative; 
}
```

becouse the div is a BLOCK element, it will take all the space in X axis, so you dont have to set the width property. By default its 100% ;)

Comment: Please don't use the word 'Cuz' in answers. Please actually type out your words. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (Write to the best of your ability)

Answer (score 0):

See a working example of a media query here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fSYSJ/

```
body { background:silver; }
#heading {
float:left;
width:100%;
padding-top:3%;
padding-bottom:1%;
font-size:55px;
color:#FFF;
position:relative;
}

#subheading {
float:left;
width:100%;
padding-top:3%;
padding-bottom:3%;
font-size:36px;
position:relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    #heading { color:red; }
    #subheading { color:red; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px)
{
    #heading { color:blue; }
    #subheading { color:blue; }
}
```

Notice I'm currently just changing the color of the headings, just adjust it to change the size instead and also adjust the break points in pixels to your liking.